# How to get the dynamic height of an img element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, height

I'm changing the `src` of an `img` and the image I load doesn't always have the same height. I'd like to get the image's height so I can correctly size and position it using jQuery.

How do I get the height of the `img` element if its height is set to auto and its parent height is also set to auto?

Trying `.parentNode` did not work for me. `.outerHeight()` and `.height()` returned `0`. What other solutions are there?

Comment: Have you tried using getComputedStyle('image node', null).height

Comment: @javipadilla yess, returns 0px ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is loaded asynchronously. You can't check its height immediately, otherwise the height returned will always be 0. You need to wait until the image is loaded and then query its height. An example:

```js
let img = document.querySelector("img");
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
 console.log(this.offsetHeight);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
```